# In Kentico, how can I export files from the database?

Tags: kentico

In Kentico, how can I export files with their correct filenames from the table 'BlobTable'?

Comment: What is the 'BlobTable'? Is it a coupled table of one of your page types or is it a custom table? What is the structure of that table? What form controls are you using to store binary data in it?

Comment: This is a clients database, and I don't know if it was a standard Kentico structure or not. I just needed to get the files out.

Answer (score 0):

Using this example:

```
Declare @sql varchar(500) 
set @sql = 'BCP "SELECT * FROM [esc_mcms].dbo.[BlobTable] where [BlobId]=4" QUERYOUT C:\Temp\blob\04.pdf -T -f C:\Temp\blob\testblob_all.fmt -S ' + @@SERVERNAME EXEC master.dbo.xp_CmdShell @sql
```

I wrote a script to generate commands that could be executed to extract all of the files stored as blobs:

```
SELECT 
          'set @sql = ''BCP "SELECT * FROM [esc_mcms].dbo.[BlobTable] where [BlobId]="'+convert(varchar,[BlobId])+' QUERYOUT C:\Temp\blob\out\'+NodeResource.name+'.'+BlobFileExt+' -T -f C:\Temp\blob\testblob_all.fmt -S '' + @@SERVERNAME EXEC master.dbo.xp_CmdShell @sql' SQL
      FROM [BlobTable], NodeResource, Node
    where BlobId=ResourceBlobId
    and Node.Id=NodeResource.Id
    and NodeResource.name != '_Content'
```